# S3 Presigned URL - There were headers present in the request which were not signed

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I wrote AWS Lambda func for the receiving S3 presing url by orderId:

```
const AWS = require("aws-sdk");

const s3 = new AWS.S3();
exports.handler = async (event) => {
    return await getUploadURL(event)
}

const getUploadURL = async function(event) {
  const orderId = event.orderId;

  const s3Params = {
    Bucket: process.env.UploadBucket,
    Key: `${orderId}.pdf`,
    Expires: parseInt(process.env.URLExpirationsSeconds),
  }

  console.log('Params: ', s3Params)

  try {
    const uploadURL = await s3.getSignedUrlPromise('getObject', s3Params)
    return {
      statusCode: 200,
      body: JSON.stringify({
        uploadURL: uploadURL,
      })
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    let errorMessage;
    if (error instanceof Error) {
      // Now TypeScript knows `error` is of type Error, and `error.message` is safe to access.
      errorMessage = error.message;
    } else {
      // If it's not an Error object, handle accordingly. 
      // This branch is a safeguard.
      errorMessage = 'An unknown error occurred';
    }

    return {
      statusCode: 500,
      body: JSON.stringify({
        message: "Could not generate the presigned URL",
        error: errorMessage,
      }),
    };
  }
}
```

I successfully can receive url but after open it receive next message:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kYXtn.png)

Maybe could somebody help me?

Comment: Can you show us how you make the request?

Comment: @jellycsc now I simply test lambda in AWS consule, add this to EVENT JSON 
{
  "orderId": 70511
}

Comment: This is not what I was asking. After you get the `uploadURL`, how do you use it?

Comment: @jellycsc Simply I paste it in browser search bar